# How to insert in one table from another table by using Join that eliminates duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a table `A` and `B` with same exact columns:

```
create or replace table a (
    a1 varchar(30),
    a2 int,
    a3 int
);

create or replace table b (
    b1 varchar(30),
    b2 int,
    b3 int
);
```

And then inserted 2 values in each:

```
insert into a values ('abc', 1, 2);
insert into a values ('abd', 1, 2);

insert into b values ('abd', 1, 2);
insert into b values ('abe', 1, 2);
```

How to make insert statement so that it inserts only records from `B` that do NOT exist in table `A` (by e.g. using join statement?)?

```
insert into table a (
    select * from b
    );
```

(without Primary Key help).
Bonus point is to check only on 2 columns if they are the same or not (e.g. `a1 != b1` and `a2 != b2`).

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify: in the example given, you'd want the row `'abe', 1, 2` inserted into table `a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `not exists` :

```
insert into a (a1, a2, a3)
     select b1, b2, b3
     from b 
     where not exists (select 1 from a where a1 = b.b1 and a2 = b.b2);
```

Comment: This worked, thank you...

Answer (score 2):

This should give you what you need:

```
insert into a 
select b.*
from b left join  a on a.a1 = b.b1 and a.a2 = b.b2
where a.a1 is null
```

Comment: This worked as well. thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
insert int a
select * from b
where (b1, b2, b3) not in (select a1, a2, a3 from a)
```

Comment: This worked as well. thanks...